# How to create a Hashmap containing a vector of Regex options for each line in a file in Rust

Tags: regex, rust, hashmap, borrow-checker

I am a Rust noob with a medium level knowledge of programming in general and have been stuck in this spot for quite a while. Essentially, I am reading from a file and performing regex to break up each line into groups that I want to process later. I am hoping to save each line in a hashmap as a vector of its groups, with the key of the hashmap being group 4.

I want to use a `String` to allow me to assign a value inside the for loop, but the `captures_iter` function is expecting a `&str`.

I am open to alternative solutions.

I alternate between two errors, and do not know a way around one without causing the other.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use regex::Regex;
use regex::Captures;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    //read file
    let input = File::open("../input.txt").unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(input);

    //ugly regex, but it does exactly what I want it to
    let re = Regex::new(r"(?:(^[[:lower:]]+|^\d+) |)(?:([[:lower:]]+|[[:upper:]]+) |)(?:([[:lower:]]+|[[:upper:]]+|\d+|) |)-> ([[:lower:]]+)$").unwrap();
    
    //hashmap to store the 'instructions' which is the regex groups, with the key of group 4
    let mut instructions : HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>> = HashMap::new();

    for line in reader.lines().into_iter() {

        let line = line.unwrap();
        println!("Line Read: {}", line);

        for caps in re.captures_iter(&line){ //this line is where I am having touble, with or without the '&' before line, I get a different error

            let groups: Vec<&str> = caps.iter()
                .map(|m| match m {
                    Some(value) => value.as_str(),
                    None => ""
                })
            .collect();

            println!("{:?}", groups); //this prints exactly what I want

            instructions.insert(groups[4], groups); //this line is the one that causes the error, because of a reference outside the loop?
        }
    }
}
```

> The error when line: `for caps in re.captures_iter(&line){` is **`line` does not live long enough**

> The error when line: `for caps in re.captures_iter(line){` is **mismatched types**

I appreciate any help or advice. Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

> P.S. This is for Advent of Code 2015, day 7. If you think I am going about this the complete wrong way also feel free to let me know.

Comment: `line` is dropped on every iteration of the loop, and `re.captures_iter` returns a reference to that string (IE, it doesn't copy the string). What this means is your reference becomes invalid on every subsequent loop. To fix this, you need to make `instructions` own the string: IE, `Vec<String>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `groups` to be a `Vec<String>` instead of `Vec<&str>`, and `instructions` to be `HashMap<String, Vec<String>>`, then it should work I think.

```
use regex::Captures;
use regex::Regex;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn main() {
    //read file
    let input = File::open("../input.txt").unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(input);

    //ugly regex, but it does exactly what I want it to
    let re = Regex::new(r"(?:(^[[:lower:]]+|^\d+) |)(?:([[:lower:]]+|[[:upper:]]+) |)(?:([[:lower:]]+|[[:upper:]]+|\d+|) |)-> ([[:lower:]]+)$").unwrap();

    //hashmap to store the 'instructions' which is the regex groups, with the key of group 4
    let mut instructions: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();

    for line in reader.lines().into_iter() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        println!("Line Read: {}", line);

        for caps in re.captures_iter(&line) {
            //this line is where I am having touble, with or without the '&' before line, I get a different error

            let groups: Vec<String> = caps
                .iter()
                .map(|m| match m {
                    Some(value) => value.as_str().to_string(),
                    None => "".to_string(),
                })
                .collect();

            println!("{:?}", groups); //this prints exactly what I want

            instructions.insert(groups[4].clone(), groups); //this line is the one that causes the error, because of a reference outside the loop?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer: although to clarify, the reason why is because `line` is dropped on every iteration. The alternative solution would be to use `fs::read_to_string`, and then you could use references rather than the owned string (as long as you keep the contents alive as long `instructions` stays alive). But there's no real reason to do that.

Comment: Thank you, these changes worked and make a lot of sense to me. I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The values you store in your hashmap go out of scope at the end of each loop iteration, which is why Rust complains about lifetimes.

```rust
// A new `line` is created on each loop iteration.
for line in reader.lines.into_iter() {
    let line = line.unwrap();

    for caps in re.captures_iter(&line) {
        // This `Vec` stores slices of `line`.
        let groups: Vec<&str> = /* ... */;

        // Here you insert values into the hashmap that reference `line`.
        instructions.insert(groups[4], groups);
    }

    // `line` goes out of scope here, invalidating the stored references to it.
}
```

In order to avoid the error you see, you need to store the data in the `HashMap` such that it outlives each loop iteration. The simplest way to do this is to make it a `HashMap<String, Vec<String>>` and convert the `&str`s to `Strings` when storing them. That will copy the string data from `line` to a separate location on the heap, which will live as long as each stored string.

```rust
// A new `line` is created on each loop iteration.
for line in reader.lines.into_iter() {
    let line = line.unwrap();

    for caps in re.captures_iter(&line) {
        // This `Vec` stores owned copies of the data in `line`.
        let groups: Vec<String> = caps
            .iter()
            .map(|m| match m {
                Some(value) => value.as_str().to_string(),
                None => String::new(),
            })
            .collect();

        // All values inserted here are owned.
        instructions.insert(groups[4].clone(), groups);
    }

    // There are no outstanding references to `line`.
}
```

I recommend checking out *The Rust Programming Language* chapters on [References and Borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) and [Validating References with Lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html) to gain a better understanding of the error you encountered.

Comment: Thanks Cormac, your explanation makes a lot of sense to me. I will give those chapters more of a look. I appreciate you taking the time to help